# AEM - Versioned clientlibs configuration conflict

Tags: osgi, aem

I'm having a problem with two htmlwriter configurations: one for the **versioned clientlibs** and the other for **link rewriting**.
Only the configuration with the higher order is working, excluding the other one.

I've tried also combining them as explained in this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57160963/how-can-i-configure-a-transformer-in-a-sling-rewriting-pipeline), but it doesn't work for me, since the versioned clientlibs stopped working.

Is there a way to make two htmlwriter configurations work together ?

Edit - Adding my merged configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
    contentTypes="text/html"
    enabled="{Boolean}true"
    generatorType="htmlparser"
    order="5000"
    paths="/content/mysite"
    serializerType="htmlwriter"
    transformerTypes="[linktype,linkchecker,versioned-clientlibs]">
    <generator-htmlparser
        jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"
        includeTags="[A,OPTION]"/>
</jcr:root>
```

Comment: What AEM version are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 6.5.10

Comment: Ok, excellent, can you share the configuration of rewriter(s)? Are you using two of them for the same content type/resource resolver? Have you actually tried to merge it? This way it should work, can I see the config?

Comment: Also, there is another problem with versioned clientlibs - because the configuration looks good to me. Due to changes of how HTML link tag is generated now, you have to update ACS: https://experienceleaguecommunities.adobe.com/t5/adobe-experience-manager/versioned-clientlibs-not-working-for-js/td-p/397642

Comment: I have version 5.0.10 and still not working

Comment: In this case, I would check whether the ACS bundle is up and running, the configuration is not overridden by another one, and also share the actual tag of the client lib that is not transformed here.

Comment: - ACS bundle is up and running
- The configuration is not overridden because the link rewriter is actually working. It is the versioned clientlib part that is not working. (If I separate the v. clientlibs from this combined configuration and assign it a higher order, it works but excluding the link rewriting conf)
- All the clientlibs should be versioned. With combined conf, no clientlib is being versioned

Comment: Have you seen anything suspicious in the logs?

Comment: Sadly, nothing strange in the logs

Comment: Above config is a single pipeline with 3 transformers piped. Wondering how would have multiple pipeline configurations with different orders? Coz you are running multiple sites on same AEM server? Anyways if its single config under /apps/APPNAME/config/rewriter, try lowering to order to 1 or -1.